# Data.Table: conditionally update values in .SD by reference

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I'm new to the data.table package.
I'm working on a big data.table (60 columns, 9 million rows)
and would like to replace all negative values with 0 in all columns.

My current solution is:

```
dt2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD,function(x) {ifelse(x < 0,0,x)})]
```

This takes approx. 8s per column.
I'd like to use the := operator and skip the function to make it faster.
But I don't know how I can reference the current column chosen by .SD

e.g.

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, .SD[<0] := 0]
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `set` way which would do the assignment in place.  Loop through the sequence of columns, then get the row index where the value is less than 0 (`i`), specify the column index in 'j' and set the value that correspond to these index to 0.

```
for(j in seq_along(dt)){
   set(dt, i = which(dt[[j]]<0), j=j, value = 0)
}
```

---

Or another option is

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) pmax(0, x))]
```

Comment: Thank you akrun!
The second option is already 4x faster.
To be honest, the "set-way" is still above my current knowledge.
Could you explain what is happening there, so I can integrate it into my code and test it?

Comment: @MarioKreutzfeldt  I updated the post with some description.  Hope it helps